# Delphi .res file changer

Tags: delphi, file, resources

I'm looking for a ready-to-use piece of code that would be able to read and modify Delphi .res files. The thing is that I need to create an application that will be compiling many Delphi projects at once (using the dcc32.exe file). However, it is necessary for me to change file version and language before compilation, and as far as I know, I have to modify the .res file to do that.

Have you come across any code that would give me an interface to .res files allowing me to modify the data contained in it? The thing is that I want to change only those two pieces of information keeping the rest unchanged. This is why I can't compile my own .res file based on a script.

An application executed from a command line would also be OK if it allows to be called with parameters and does what I need it to do.

Thank you very in advance!

Comment: Also you can vote for QC #70567 (do not store version information in the compiled .res file - to allow for easier manipulation), and QC #70564 (allow version informations to be set from the command line)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If all you need is to add file version resource then create `appver.rc` file, compile it with `brcc32` and in one of your app unit (for example `appver.pas`) add `{$R appver.res}` (as Marian noticed you must turn off Delphi project option to include version info).

I created command line programs that increase build numbers in `.rc` file, create new branch/tag in SVN with new version in branch name, compiles `.rc` to `.res`, and build application.

My `.rc` files with such info (Polish language) looks like:

```
#define IDR_VERSION1  1
IDR_VERSION1 VERSIONINFO LOADONCALL MOVEABLE DISCARDABLE IMPURE
FILEVERSION 7,28,7,17
PRODUCTVERSION 7,28,7,17
FILEFLAGSMASK VS_FFI_FILEFLAGSMASK
FILEFLAGS 0
FILEOS VOS_DOS_WINDOWS32
FILETYPE VFT_DLL
FILESUBTYPE 0
{
 BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
 {
  BLOCK "041504E2"
  {
   VALUE "CompanyName", "xxx\0"
   VALUE "FileDescription", "yyy\0"
   VALUE "ProductName", "zzz\0"
   VALUE "FileVersion", "7.28.7.17\0"
   VALUE "ProductVersion", "7.28.7.17\0"
  }

 }

 BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
 {
  VALUE "Translation", 0x0415, 1250
 }

}
```

Comment: +1 for addressing the cause and not just dealing with the symptoms. It might be worth mentioning in your answer that for this to work in the IDE as well, you need to turn off "include version" in the project's options. Something the IDE will not allow you to do for dll projects, you may have to "hack" the dproj for that by hand.

Answer (score 3):

For all things .res, look at Colin Wilson's "XN Resource Editor", for which he provides the source code: http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm
And probably all you need is his resource utility library:
http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d9resourceutils.htm
I haven't used this source, but if I needed it, that's the first place I'd look. His resource editor is very useful, btw.

Comment: the links are down

Answer (score 3):

There is [ChangeRes](http://www.tiriss.com/changeres/index.html) which seems to match your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Check out sources:

http://code.google.com/p/gedemin/source/browse/trunk#trunk/Gedemin/Utility/IncVerRC

It is our utility which reads .RC file with version information and increments build number. We use it inside our build process. Here is an excerpt:

```
incverrc.exe ..\gedemin\gedemin.rc
"%delphi_path%\brcc32.exe" -fogedemin.res -i..\images gedemin.rc
"%delphi_path%\dcc32.exe" -b gedemin.dpr
```

The utility uses TIncVerRc class written by Chris Morris.

Answer (score 1):

Check Resource Tuner Console on [www.heaventools.com](http://www.heaventools.com/). They position that product for tasks like yours. Also there's a free [rcstamp tool on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/rcstamp.aspx).